# Forbid specific functions in clang compiler

Tags: objective-c, security, printf, malloc, clang

Is there a way to forbid the usage of potential unsafe functions like malloc, _memcpy and others from being used *by* the clang compiler when compiling objective c code?

Comment: Why do you think that they are unsafe?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/BufferOverflows.html

Comment: Did you understand the article? Can you describe a situation when the *compiler* uses one of these functions to create unsafe code? Can you describe a situation which creates safe code by replacing these functions?